# How to use Regex.Replace in this situation?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace

I was using a regex to check strings for their correctness (I want to allow the characters `A-Z`,`a-z`,`*`,`space`,`-`,`&`,`%`,`.`,`/`,`+`). My code is something like this:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^[A-Z0-9.$/+%\\- ]+$");
string myString = "ABCDEFGH 12345 $%...     A"; //string ok

if (r.IsMatch(myString))
  System.Console.WriteLine("String alright!");
```

This is working and everything is fine. Now I just thought, maybe I could handle non-correct strings also. I would like to replace the non-correct (non regex valid) characters in the string with `-`. That could be done with `Regex.Replace`. So I made this:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^[A-Z0-9.$/+%\\- ]+$");
string myString = "HELLO WÖRLD ß~# 50.00$"; //Ö,ß,~,# should be replaced by -

if (r.IsMatch(myString))
  System.Console.WriteLine("String alright!");
else
  myString = Regex.Replace(myString, r.ToString(), "-");

System.Console.WriteLine(myString);
```

Well this is so not working! As output I get:

```
HELLO WÖRLD ß~# 50.00$
```

What am I missing? The problem is the regex right? I can check if a string is correct or not, but I cannot use with this regex the Regex.Replace function correctly. Is there a way to use 1 regex for checking if the string is valid AND to use `Regex.Replace`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to (match and) replace characters that are not matching your the characters in your validation expression you need another expression to specifically match those characters. For example:

```
[^A-Z0-9.$/+%\- ]
```

Which could be used as:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"[^A-Z0-9.$/+%\- ]", "-");
```

Comment: Ah alright. Probably I do not fully understand the difference between your regex and my regex... but this one is working. The only thing I have to change after this is my if statemant to     '(!r.IsMatch(myString))' and then everything is fine. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't actually make sense.
If `r.IsMatch()` returns false, you know that the regex doesn't match the string, so replacing any matches isn't going to have an effect.  (there are no matches)

Instead, you should create a regex that matches any *invalid* characters, check whether it *doesn't* match, and if it does, call `.Replace()`.

---

Also, you're misusing regexes.

If you have a `Regex` instance, you should call its `Replace` *instance* method:

```
myString = r.Replace(myString, "-");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your replace isn't happening because regex doesn't find anything to replace.

What you can do, to use the same regex, is to convert 'myString' to chars and check each char for validity.

Example (from java, but should be easy enough to understand):

```
if (r.IsMatch(myString)){
            System.Console.WriteLine("String alright!");
}  else {

    // java iteration
    for(int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++){
        Character c = myString.charAt(i);
        if(!c.toString().matches(reg)){
            myString = myString.replace(c.toString(), "-");
        }
    }

}
```